# How to find which element failed comparison between arrays in Kotlin?

Tags: arrays, kotlin

I'm writing automated tests for one site. There's a page with all items added to the cart. Maximum items is 58. Instead of verification of each element one by one I decided to create 2 `arrays` filled with `strings`: 1 with correct names : `String` and 1 with names : `String` I got from the site. Then I compare those 2 arrays with `contentEquals`. 
If that comparison fails, how do I know which element exactly caused comparison fail?

Short simple of what I have now:

```
@Test
fun verifyNamesOfAddedItems () {

val getAllElementsNames = arrayOf(materials.text, element2.text, 
element3.text...) 
val correctElementsNames = arrayOf("name1", "name2", "name3"...)
val areArraysEqual = getAllElementsNames contentEquals correctElementsNames
if (!areArraysEqual) {
    assert(false)
} else {
    assert(true)
}

}
```

This test fails if 2 arrays are not the same but it doesn't show me the details, so is there a way to see more details of fail, e.g. element that failed comparison? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using a matcher library like Hamcrest or AssertJ in tests. They provide much better error messages for cases like this. In this case with Hamcrest it would be:

```
import org.hamcrest.Matchers.*

assertThat(getAllElementsNames, contains(*correctElementsNames))

// or just
assertThat(getAllElementsNames, contains("name1", "name2", "name3", ...))
```

There are also matcher libraries made specifically for Kotlin: https://github.com/kotlintest/kotlintest, https://yobriefca.se/expect.kt/, https://github.com/winterbe/expekt, https://github.com/MarkusAmshove/Kluent, probably more. Tests using them should be even more readable, but I haven't tried any of them. Look at their documentation and examples and pick the one you like.

Comment: `assertThat` didn't work for me, unfortunately, but Kluent library did everything well. Thanks a lot. It has a bug though (it shows previous element from the array in error message) but I can live with that :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the intersection between the two collections. Intersection will be the common elements. After than removing the intersection collection from the collection you want to perform the test will give you the complementary elements.

```
val intersection = getAllElementsNames.intersect(correctElementsNames)
getAllElementsNames.removeAll(intersection)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Getting "Type inference failed" error for `interset()` function. Is it applicable to `arrayOf` type?

Comment: Yes, `inteserct` is extension function for `Array<out T>` https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/intersect.html

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't work. Probably, I do something wrong. I initialize array like this: `val getAllElementsNames : Array<out String> = arrayOf("String", "String", "String"...)`. Is it correct? Thanks!